# ZFS NFSv4 ACLs not displaying on the client side

Tags: linux, nfs, zfs, acl, posix

I'm running ZFS [2.0.3] on Debian 10 with NFSv4 shares, setting `xattr: on` and `acltype: posixacl`, with my export using `zfs set sharenfs` being:

```
rw=@@hosts,async,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash
```

- I can successfully mount the shares on my clients and the permissions I set with `setfacl` are applied and working properly, but when I try to verify the permissions using `getfacl`, the ACLs are not displayed; however, on the server-side, they show up properly.
- I set ACLs via:

  ```
  setfacl -d -m u:testuser:rwx testdir 
  setfacl    -m u:testuser:rwx testfile
  ```

Is this expected behaviour and if not, how can I make them show up on the client-side?

Comment: did you use `-o acl` when mounting on client side ? I also used `zfs set share.nfs=on ZPOOL/dir ` and `zfs set share.nfs.aclok=on ZPOOL/dir`

Comment: I have tried it both with `-o acl` and without. It did not change anything, ACLs are still not showing up on the client-side. I didn't find those settings you mentioned in my ZFS (Debian).